# android - approach to export logcat events

Tags: android, crash

My android app has entered beta and a tester is encountering the android reporting the app has crashed. Is there a recommended approach for collecting logcat entries and emailing or moving the event off device?  Testers have no access to the source code or android dev studio.

Have seen android report crash dumps and offer the choice to download the dump off device.  Any pointers to an approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an analytics tool like crashlytics. When crashes occur they are logged in its dashboard, here you can view the stacktrace for the crash just like you would in the logcat.

Comment: Will look into crashlytics.  Is this something I build into the app and does it produce output the beta's could send to me?

Comment: You implement it in the app by importing the library via the gradle, then you initialise crashlytics in the app controller and it automatically sends the crashes to crashlytics, no more code needed. The betas would not need to send anything, as soon as the app crashed, you would have the crash report in crashlytics. You can even sign up for email alerts that send an email on every crash. Please remember to upvote and accept the answer if it helps you!

Comment: The easiest way to implement crashlytics is to install the fabric plugin in to android studio and then let the plug in put the code in for you!

Comment: Have an approach that does not use crashlytics.  Appreciate the pointer but kept policy of not using 3rd party code.

Comment: @T.Barrett third party code is there to make our lives easier, why reinvent the wheel? But that is your choice, what did you opt for in the end, I'd be interested to know